# On the word "dem" in a relative clause

Tags: dative

I have the following sentence:

> Das Lagerfeuer, in dem ich meine Marshmallows brate, ist sehr heiß.

The campfire, in which I roast my marshmallows, is very hot.

Am I correct in saying that the article used in this relative clause is "dem" as the Lagerfeuer is receiving the action of me roasting the marshmellows?

Comment: I changed the title, for the question is not, as the title had previously stated, about the preposition _in_ but about the word _dem_.

Comment: The question is about the case that is used with the two-way preposition *in*. I suggest to revert that change.

Comment: Das steht aber mit keinem Wort im Text. Es wird gefragt, ob man etwas auf bestimmte Art sagen kann. Das kann man, wie ich in meiner Antwort erläutert habe, nicht.

Comment: Es kann natürlich auch sein, dass die Frage einfach schwammig formuliert wurde. Wenn man nämlich davon ausgeht, dass _Artikel_ mit _Demonstrativpronomen_ verwechselt wurde und dass für den OP _das_ und _dem_ zwei verschiedene Artikel anstatt zwei verschiedene Deklinationsformen desselben Artikels sind, dann kann man die Frage auch so interpretieren: _"Am I correct in saying that the case of the demonstrative pronoun 'dem' ..."_ Und dann wäre deutlich, dass es hier um den Fall geht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You ask ***Where** do I roast my marshmallows?* answer: **in dem** Lagerfeuer (dative).

Also:
*Ich brate meine Marshmallows in dem Lagerfeuer, das sehr heiß ist.* (and not in another one which is not so hot).
*Ich brate meine Mashmallows im Lagerfeuer.* (general statement).

(I guess its clearer in these cases where no relative sentence is involved, but the way it works here is the same as above.)

Comment: So it’s dative because you ask *where* and not *whither*?

Comment: @CarstenS: yes.

Comment: The fire is not receiving the action. It is simply the *place* of action.

Answer (score 4):

> Das Lagerfeuer, in *dem* ich meine Marshmallows brate, ist sehr heiß.

Quote: *"Am I correct in saying that the article used in this relative clause is 'dem' ...?"*

Not exactly. Here, *dem* is not an article but a relative pronoun. It indicates that the content of the relative clause (*Marshmellows braten*) is referred back to the last noun in the preceding clause (*Lagerfeuer*). It is in dative case (*dem* instead of *das*), because the *Lagerfeuer* is the location where the action of roasting takes place.

Notice that the noun referred to does not need to be the subject. It can also be an object, as in

> Ich<sub>(subject)</sub> fotografiere das Lagerfeuer<sub>(object)</sub>, in *dem* ich meine Marshmellows brate.